# How to use union query in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a query in core php but i want to convert into Laravel, i am trying to do but that is giving the error. I don't know the exact method which i can use for this
here is the core query

```
   select  mon,year,
        combo,
       registered,
       forwardedbycmo,
       clarification,
       noaction,
       disposed,mon_srno,undertaken
from monthly_activities
union
select extract('month' from actiondate) as mon,extract('year' from actiondate) as year,
        extract('year' from actiondate)|| '-' ||to_char(to_timestamp (extract('month' from actiondate)::text, 'MM'), 'TMMon') as combo,
       sum(case when actioncode = '00' then 1 else 0 end) as registered,
       sum(case when actioncode = '4T' and fromorg='CMOFF' then 1 else 0 end) as forwardedbycmo,
       sum(case when actioncode = '4D' and fromorg='CMOFF' then 1 else 0 end) as clarification,
       sum(case when actioncode = '10' then 1 else 0 end) as noaction,
       sum(case when actioncode = '50' then 1 else 0 end) as disposed,null as mon_srno,
        sum(case when actioncode = '40' and fromorg='CMOFF' then 1 else 0 end) as undertaken

from actionhistory where extract(month from actiondate)=extract(month from current_date)
and extract(year from actiondate)=extract(year from current_date)
 group by mon,year order by year,mon;
```

> and laravel query is

```
$first = MonthlyActivity::select('mon','year','combo','registered','forwardedbycmo',
       'clarification',
       'noaction',
       'disposed','mon_srno','undertaken')->get();

        $second = MonthlyActivity::select(extract('month' from actiondate) as mon,extract('year' from actiondate) as year,
        extract('year' from actiondate)|| '-' ||to_char(to_timestamp (extract('month' from actiondate)::text, 'MM'), 'TMMon') as combo,
       sum(case when actioncode = '00' then 1 else 0 end) as registered,
       sum(case when actioncode = '4T' and fromorg='CMOFF' then 1 else 0 end) as forwardedbycmo,
       sum(case when actioncode = '4D' and fromorg='CMOFF' then 1 else 0 end) as clarification,
       sum(case when actioncode = '10' then 1 else 0 end) as noaction,
       sum(case when actioncode = '50' then 1 else 0 end) as disposed,null as mon_srno,
        sum(case when actioncode = '40' and fromorg='CMOFF' then 1 else 0 end) as undertaken

from actionhistory where extract(month from actiondate)=extract(month from current_date)
and extract(year from actiondate)=extract(year from current_date))->groupBy('mon','year')->orderBy('year','mon')->get();
 $result =  $first->union($second);

//$users = DB::table('users')->whereNull('last_name')->union($first)->get();
        return view('show',['monthly' => $result]);
```

Comment: This is a really ugly query.. I really think that it could be simplified by changing the db architecture.. you should consider that..

Comment: @MateiMihai: I cann't change the db structure tat is already assgined to me. Please let me know is there any way to execute this query as it is in laravel?

Comment: my suggestion to you is to restructure this query builder and make it looks better :)

Answer (score 0):

As per your question title, [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#unions) is union reference for Laravel.
But seeing your problem as you have used native sql functions such as `extract()`, I will advise you to run query as raw query.

For heads up:

You use: `$var = DB::connection()->getPdo()->quote($var);`
to escape any variable you are using in query.

Prepare your raw query and put it in a variable like:

```
$query = 'SELECT ....';
```

Then you run it like:

```
$result = DB::select($query,[]);
```

Dont forget to include DB class at top of controller:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
```

I am sorry I cannot give a lot of time to actually make a laravel query for you, so I suggested here which might help you go on.Good Luck!

Comment: $var = DB::connection()->getPdo()->quote($var); where i can use this line under controller?

Comment: No Problem. Think about closing this thread if your problem has resolved by accepting the answer on stack overflow. Thanks.

Comment: $var = DB::connection()->getPdo()->quote($var); where i can use this line under controller?

Comment: Yes inside controller after receiving input variable: `$var = $request->input('var_name');` , after that you escape it with that line.

Comment: its give me error BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2445:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::connection()

Comment: Did you add: `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;` in top of the controller?

Comment: i don't have input request just want to fetch the data using above query and pass it to view file

Comment: Then you dont need: `$var = DB::connection()->getPdo()->quote($var)` at all

Comment: yes i include the use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB; after namespace its give the below error FatalErrorException in MonthlyActivityController.php line 6:
Cannot use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB as DB because the name is already in use

Comment: Can u list here all namespaces you are using in that controller?

Comment: namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use App\MonthlyActivity;

Comment: and this is function code inside the controller....$query=""; $result = MonthlyActivity::select($query,[]);

     return view('show',['monthly' => $result]);

Comment: Now page runs and don't show any error but data is not shown

Comment: You are including : `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;` two times, you should include it only once

Comment: i remove that but query data is not showing. How can i check either query is running or not

Comment: You should go to: root/storage/logs/laravel.log - open this file..delete all and save..then run the program one more time and then open the file again to see whats the problem.

Comment: its show nothing in the log after following your instructions